# about magic square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, magic-square

Let us define a magic square as a matrix whose entries are rational numbers and have the same sum on columns, rows and both main diagonals. I am trying to prove the exercise :

For every $n\ge4$, there is a $n×n$ magic square $A$ such that for every integer $m\ge2$, $A^m$ is not a magic square.

I have found examples for even $n\ge4$ and odd $n\ge7$, respectively of the form:
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
n-2 & 0\\
0 & S-E
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
  \begin{pmatrix}
n-3 & 0\\
0 & S-E-D
  \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $S$ is the matrix with all entries equal to $1$, $E$ is the identity matrix, $D$ is the matrix whose second diagonal are the $1$s and all other $0$.

What's left is the $n=5$ case. Please show me an example of that or even better, a single one covers all the cases.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Magic squares are required to have entries consist precisely of the numbers $1$ through $n^2$, not merely have the same sum on rows, columns, and main diagonals.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Not necessarily. In the terminology of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square), what you refer to is more specifically a "normal" magic square

Comment: @BenGrossmann: TIL... thanks.

Comment: Thank you, I have fixed it partly.

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2225182/1508) calls them magic square matrices, which seems less controversial.

Comment: After employ minus numbers, I got an answer. Thank you all.